# How to create ics file that allow adding attendee on creation of Google calendar event

Tags: icalendar

I am trying to create an `.ics` for Google Calendar, but when I try to add this event to my Google Calendar using the file, there isn't anyone the event's attendee list.

```
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//PYVOBJECT//NONSGML Version 1//EN
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:20191205T041804Z - 44748@odoo-vagrant
DTSTART:20200103T140000Z
DTEND:20200103T150000Z
ATTENDEE:MAILTO:dang.nguyen@novobi.com
ATTENDEE:MAILTO:admin@yourcompany.example.com
CREATED:20191205T041803Z
DESCRIPTION:Phone: (098) 159-4793\nEmail: dang.nguyen@novobi.com\n
DTSTAMP:20191205T041804Z
LOCATION:https://zoom.us/j/308566271
ORGANIZER:MAILTO:admin@yourcompany.example.com
SUMMARY:Odoo Accounting with Dang Nguyen
BEGIN:VALARM
ACTION:AUDIO
DESCRIPTION:15 Minute(s)\, by e-mail
TRIGGER;RELATED=START:PT15M
END:VALARM
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Can anyone help me with this issue ?